# PHP loop stops unexpectly

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a table (table3) in MYSQL with 99 text fields (field1, filed2, ...,field99). I wanted to count the non-empty values of each field so I wrote a simple php script with a for loop as below:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++)
{
  $sqlstm = "SELECT COUNT(field$i) FROM table3 WHERE field$i IS NOT NULL AND field$i <> '';";
  $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlstm);
  if($r)
  {
    while($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($r)) 
    {   
        echo "<p>$row[0]</p>\n"; 
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "field $i error: " . mysqli_error($dbc);
  }
}
```

But the loop stopped after showing four values (field1 to filed4) and no error message. I do have all 99 fields with data in  table3 and I could run the query manually for any field. Could this due to browser timeout?
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: remove `@` in front of `mysqli_query` to get possible error messages

Comment: OT: why do you use a `while` loop? The query always returns exactly 1 row, you don't need a loop.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon He's displaying the error with `mysqli_error($dbc)`.

Comment: Meanwhile, also look at your browser's HTML page source. The unescaped `$row[0]` can be a source of broken HTML.  Wrap it as `htmlspecialchars($row[0])` to avoid that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It's just a number `COUNT($field$i)`, why would you need to escape it?

Comment: @Barmar you're right, I missed it

Comment: @Barmar Indeed - I missed the COUNT()

Comment: remove @ from, @mysqli_query($dbc, $sqlstm); first to see error

Comment: @sany2k8 See my response to Lorenzo when he suggested the same thing.

Comment: @Barmar: keep owning the people who don't read carefully! :D

Comment: Thanks for help. I agree that I don't need while-loop since COUNT() is just one value. But my problem is why the for-loop stops with just four values.

Comment: Can you edit your question with `SHOW CREATE tablename` or use http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @Barmar sorry for the mistake sir

Comment: I take it back. It certainly can't **hurt** to remove the `@` before the calls. Maybe something weird is going on, and those error messages might help.

Comment: @user3334714 you might try to loop through the 99 fields within the SQL query so you make sure that it is no browser timeout or anything. For example: create a while-loop | create a counter | do the same as in your PHP code

Answer (score -4):

```
 $sqlstm = "SELECT COUNT(field$i) FROM table3
```

you are selecting the columns here, your table has 99 rows but apperantly only 4 columns

what you could better do is

```
$sqlstm = "SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE (column name) IS NOT NULL";
$count = 0
for($sqlstm as $one) {
    $count = $count + 1;
}
echo($count);
```

or something along those lines

Comment: If his table doesn't have those columns, why isn't he getting an error saying that the colunn doesn't exist when he echoes `mysqli_error($dbc)`?

Comment: He said that the query works when he tries to run it manually.

Comment: Your suggested new code never actually executes the query. Selecting `COUNT()` is better than selecting all the rows, since it doesn't have to send all the data back to the client.

Comment: Thanks. My table does have 99 fields and the query is correct since I could run it manually for any field and the for-loop did get four correct counts.

Comment: It looks more like a browser timeout than anything else. I changed the for-loop to for($i = 5; $i <= 99; $i++1) and the counts of field5, field6, and field7 were displayed.